# Can I bypass a pull-cord switch by connecting the two wires?

Tags: ceiling-fan

The chain broke on my ceiling fan light. I don't need it as I have a wall switch. Can I connect the two wires going into the light switch and just use the wall switch?

[image]

Comment: Do you only have a single wall switch, or separate switches for the light and fan?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can just connect those two wires with a rated connector and use the wall switch.

Optionally, you could just buy a new pull chain switch for a few bucks and install that.